# Is it possible to add html inside a title attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to put actual html code inside a title attribute on a table row element?  My goal is to pop-up not only text but some info-graphics along with it, so a mouseover event thats not a modal would be great.  Am I going in the wrong direction?

This table is already using jquery datatables but I don't believe it can do that sort of event.

```
<tr title='This activity will be open to registration on April 31st' >
.....
</tr>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a bootstraps tooltip?

Comment: that's not a title tag. It's an attribute. You can't put HTML in an attribute.

Comment: Yes it is possible to put an html string inside a title attribute(if escaped properly.) However the html will not render as the tooltip, instead you will get the html string. You'll have to intercept the tooltip (or replace it) with a javascript or css solution that shows and hides an element containing the desired html.

Comment: Did you try? what happened?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nope. You'd need to create your own title substitute with JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

No.

HTML can't be placed in an attribute.

If the goal is to have a pop-up with rich content, then you need to handle this via javascript. In addition, from an accessibility standpoint, you likely don't want to put that amount of content into the title attribute anyways, so going the JS route is going to solve a few problems for you. Google 'JS Tooltip' for dozens of options.

Answer (score 5):

Native tooltips do not use HTML. jQuery UI tooltips would be very useful here.

Demo: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

**EDIT**: You would need to use the *content* option to use markup instead of the title attribute.

```
$(".text")
    .tooltip({ content: '<b style="color: red">Tooltip</b> <i>text</i>' });
```

Here's a Fiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/acbabis/64Q2m/

Comment: does not seem to work with jqueryui 1.8.23 - maybe later versions support html? (actually I am having a number of issues - like not being able to set the content as well)

Comment: @ryan2johnson9 It looks like `.tooltip` was added in version 1.9 of jQueryUI, so your guess is correct. http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: Well I do have the .tooltip method available to me and it does change the style of the tooltip, I just cannot set content and it also does not show html properly. Maybe that was an improvement in 1.9  not sure.

Comment: Not sure either, @ryan2johnson9. One thing you can try is invoking `.tooltip` then invoking `.html` on the child element

Comment: silly me - I also have bootstrap installed, so I think my .tooltip() call is using the bootstrap one. and using `.tooltip({html:true})` works

Answer (score 4):

You can use [jquery ui tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) plugin for showing custom title

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct way to render HTML code written inside a tooltip. However, if you are using jQueryUI (or, if you can) then the code below will show the HTML effect (render) and not the HTML code in the tooltip.

**Requirements**: jQuery, jQueryUI.js, jQueryUI.css

HTML Code:

```
<tr data-title='This activity will be open to registration on <b>April 31st</b>'>.....</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
        $( document ).tooltip({
              items: '[title], [data-title]',
              track:true,
              content: function(){
                  var element = $( this );
                    if ( element.is( "[title]" ) ) {
                      return element.attr( "title" );
                    }
                    if ( element.is( "[data-title]" ) ) {
                      return element.attr( "data-title" );
                    }
              }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of focusing on the title attribute, enclose a popup message with  tags inside the target `<td></td>` (table data element). Then put a class in that td to control the div with CSS, hiding it first, then making its contents visible when the mouse hovers over the specific table data element. Something like this:

```
<tr><td class="info-tooltip">This activity will be open to registration on April 31st <div>[ *the contents you would want to popup here* ]</div></td></tr>
```

Your CSS then might be something like:

```
td.info-tooltip div {

display:none;

}

td.info-tooltip:hover {

position:relative;
cursor:pointer; 

}

td.info-tooltip:hover div {

position:absolute; /* this will let you align the popup with flexibility */
top: 0px; /* change this depending on how far from the top you want it to align */
left: 0px; /* change this depending on how far from the left you want it align */
display:block; 
width: 500px; /* give this your own width */

}
```

Comment: Interesting idea but I'd like it to pop open on the entire row, not a single td element.

Answer (score 3):

Using Bootstrap Tooltips one can do the following

`<span title="Some <b>bold words</b>" data-toggle='tooltip' data-html='true'>this has an html supported tooltip</span>`

for me it happens automatically but you might need to trigger it with javascript.

`$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})`

[docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/)

Comment: Is this only in Bootstrap 4?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap version v3.3.7

Answer (score 0):

I think a good option is to put that content inside a data attribute, something like this:

```
<div data-tooltip="Some information I want to show">
    Actual content
</div>
```

And then, write a simple jQuery plugin that shows that content inside an element upon hover over.