# Anchor tag inside title attribute

Tags: html

I need to show message in tooltip which contains a link.

I have used the below code in html:

```
<div class="col-xs-2" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Please click <a href='www.google.com'>here</a> for more details.></div>
```

However I am getting error in my double codes or it show unexpected token.

Please suggest me to resolve this !!!

Comment: What's the point of doing this? As you hover over the element, the tool tip is shown with the anchor element (a tag) but if you want to click on it, you have to move the mouse to the tool tip but as soon as you do that, the too tip disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the closing quote for the `title` attribute, change it to this:

```
<div class="col-xs-2" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Please click <a href='www.google.com'>here</a> for more details."></div>
                                                                                                                  ^^^
```

And just pointing out, you cannot use html within title attribute, its not gonna render. You will have to use other methods to achieve similar results.

Comment: Yes I added double quotes. But this says "If the attribute is enclosed in quotation marks, the quotation marks must match".
I think the problem may be in single quotes in the link.

Comment: What thing gives you that error? Can you gimme more details?

Comment: It shows "Please click" as green underlined in html while hovering, I am getting this message.

Comment: Still unclear what you are saying... can you please provide a JSFiddle showing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-2" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Please click &lt;a href='www.google.com'&gt;here&lt;/a&gt; for more details.">test</div>
```

Demo Link https://jsfiddle.net/wh6ov2wt/

Comment: I don't want to show anchor tag in my tooltip. I just want to make "here" as link.

Answer (score 0):

[Attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47713704/7720153)

HTML code written inside a tooltip can't be rendered without javascript. If you use jQueryUI then the code below will show the HTML effect and not the HTML code in the tooltip.

**Requirements**: jQuery, jQueryUI.js, jQueryUI.css

JavaScript:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).tooltip({
    items: '[title]',
    track: true,
    content: function() {
      var element = $(this);
      if (element.is("[title]")) {
        return element.attr("title");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Kindly <span title='This <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">link</a> will be open to registration on <b>April 31st</b>'> hover me</span> for an important message.
```

Answer (score 0):

a tooltip (title attribute) only takes text and the browser won't consider any html in there.
To achieve this you have to implement your own tooltip template.

Here's a way to do it using css only :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

div:hover>p {
  display: block;
}


/* the p tag (our tooltip) is hidden by default */

div>p {
  display: none;
}

div>p {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 110px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}


/* This is for thr triangle part can be ignored */

div>p:before {
  content: '';
  border: 10px solid;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>Hover Over Me
  <p class="tooltip">Please click <a href='www.google.com'>here</a> for more details.</p>
</div>
```