# How to add HTML tags inside Title attribue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to add HTML tags inside `title` attribute as a tool tip.When mouse hover i can see all text what i typed in title instead of the HTML dom.I know tool tip show what ever type inside it.But i would like to know is it possible to add HTML tags inside title attribute.

**Code Snippet**

```
var nameTemplate ='<div title="<span>ok</span>"></div>';
```

**When mouse hover shows me as**

```
<span>ok</span>
```

Comment: it is possible to add html tags inside attribute, howerver it is not considered as good practice.

Comment: Use a third party jQuery tooltip plugin instead that allows displaying HTML in your tooltips.

Comment: You cannot do that with pure HTML, you need to use JS for custom tooltips

Comment: @Mr.Alien guess you'll need some CSS too, but that would be the most beautiful option imho `:)`

Comment: @Tarekis you can use CSS, we do make custom tooltips these days but we cannot parse HTML in that case :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien indeed, although OP's exampe looks so simple, i doubt he actually needs to parse HTML at all `:)`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145187/is-it-possible-to-add-html-inside-a-title-attribute