# How to add html tags in title attribute of an element?

Tags: php, html

I have a table and I want to add a title attribute to every td.

The title text contains html tags also like for example `<p>testing <b>title</b></p>`

When use this text as the value of the title attribute, and hover the mouse over the element, it also displays the html tags.

```
<td title="<p>testing <b>title</b></p>">abc</td>
```

Is there any way to use the correct formatting in the title attribute?

I am doing this in Drupal but if a php solution is present then I can use the php.

Comment: Yes you can. But the browser will display them literally as `<p>testing <b>title</b></p>`. May I suggest that you Google "Tooltip Plugin <you favorite js library>"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145187/is-it-possible-to-add-html-inside-a-title-attribute

Comment: …or lots of others you could have found by doing something we call “basic research”. https://www.google.com/search?q=html+title+attribute+with+html+tags+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

You can't use html tags in html attributes (which in your case is *title*).

Instead **you need to use JavaScript and HTML to create own custom tooltip** which will be displayed like title attribute. For example you can use this library:

https://popper.js.org/tooltip-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Change (`<`) to (`&lt;`) and (`>`) to (`&gt;`):

```
title="&lt;p&gt;testing &lt;b&gt;title&lt;/b&gt;&lt;/p&gt;"**
```