# How we can use html content in title using vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I have data like this:

```
 {
           "content": "Application Filed <br>April 2007 - 0.0 Years from filing",
        },
        {
            "content": "Non-Final  May 2009 - 2.06 Years from accident",
        },
        {
            "content": "Interview <br> August 2009 - 2.29 Years from accident",
        },
        {
            "content": "Final  <br> November 2009 - 2.57 Years from accident",
        },
        {
            "content": "Request for Continuous<br>February 2010 - 2.82 Years from accident",
        },
```

And I want to use this content key value on hover ex:

In above data there is "**br**" tag appears like this (shown in picture).

[image]

But I want to use text like HTML means text after the **br** tag appears in the next line right now they appear in the same line with **br** tag.

And what I want in hover is shown below:

```
Final
November 2009 - 2.57 Years from accident
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145187/is-it-possible-to-add-html-inside-a-title-attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can use [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

```
<div v-html="item.content"></div>
```

Comment: Also, note that if you're going to pass user-defined strings in `v-html`, it might be a good idea to sanitize them first ;)

Comment: @Terry - I want to show item.content on title hover, right now I'm using: title="item.content" but it's not rendering html content in title