# How to hover the table using utext

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have an issue with `utext` in thymeleaf. I want to show a table as a hover.

This is my code

```
<td class="CellWithHtmlContent" th:title="${event.note}">
                <span class="CellContent" ></span>
                <span th:if="${event.note != null}"
                      th:utext="${!#strings.startsWith(event.note,'<') ? #strings.abbreviate(event.note, 60) : 'More'}"></span>
            </td>
```

I have used `th:title` to show the table when hovering. But it just show the html code. Using `th:utext`, can show the table properly. but It isn't act as a hover. Is there any way to use `th:utext` inside the `th:title`?

Like this --> `th:title = utext(${event.note})`

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf does not support this. It is not possible to have a browser render HTML in a `title` attribute. See [Is it possible to add html inside a title attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145187/is-it-possible-to-add-html-inside-a-title-attribute)

You will need to use something like https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/

Add this JavaScript snippet to your page:

```html
<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {

            tippy('.tooltip', {
                content(reference) {
                    const id = reference.getAttribute('data-tooltipid');
                    const template = document.getElementById(id);
                    return template.innerHTML;
                },
                allowHTML: true
            });
        });
</script>
```

Now, add something like this:

```
<td class="CellWithHtmlContent" th:title="${event.note}">
                <span class="CellContent" ></span>
                <span th:if="${event.note != null}"
                      th:attr="data-tooltipid=${'cell-tooltip-'+event.id}"></span>
            </td>
```

(I assumed `event` has an `id`. You will need something to make the tooltip reference unique for each tooltip on the current page).

Now, also have some hidden HTML on the page that will be loaded into the tooltip by the Tippy library:

```
<div th:id="${'cell-tooltip-'+event.id}" class="hidden">
  <span th:if="${event.note != null}"
                      th:utext="${!#strings.startsWith(event.note,'<') ? #strings.abbreviate(event.note, 60) : 'More'}"></span>
</div>
```

It is important that the `id` of the hidden HTML matches with the `data-tooltipid` for the tooltip to work.